# RecycleView.Adapter?

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have created a RecycleView Adapter but have many confuson related to this adapter , I know how to  use this but not sure about the logic behing this adpater,please help

```
 class RecycleAdpapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdpapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context cn;
private String[] desc;
private int[] img;
public RecycleAdpapter(String[] de,int[] im,Context context){
    this.desc=de;
    this.img=im;
    this.cn=context;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CardView cardView;

    public ViewHolder(CardView cv) {
        super(cv);
        this.cardView = cv;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public RecycleAdpapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       Log.v("asda","THIS IS ONCREATE");
        CardView cv = (CardView) 
  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.v("DASD","THIS IS ONBIND");
        CardView cardView =holder.cardView;
        ImageView iv= (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Drawable drawable =  ContextCompat.getDrawable(cn,img[position]);
        iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        TextView tv =(TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(desc[position]);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.v("hello","THIS GET CALLED");
        return desc.length;
    }


}
```

Q1. We are creating View holders in the onCreateViewBinder() , and binding the data in onBindViewHolder() but we are not telling the adapter that how many view holder it have to create , like i have five pizza so there is no code here asking adapter to create 5 pizza, so how it come to know?

Q2. what if i had only 2 items in the data,how will it get information about that,now i have only 2 cardview to create ,how will it know that onBindViewHolder() has to run for only two positions ?

Q3. What is the work of getItemCount()?

Comment: yes, may be if you put handler.post inside on create than  compiler will periodically call that method inside your handler.post and there would be instance of oncreate too

Comment: Yup the runnable will be invoked after the `onCreate` method execution. Since you're not creating any new thread with the handler

Comment: actually i am using a handler.post() inside it there is handler.postdelayed(this,1000),they are making a kind of endless loop and everything is inside a method runtime(), and i am using that method in onCreate() , so my question is after calling the runtime() inside onCreate() does the handler.post() of runtime() will be executed after the completion of onCreate() method??

Comment: @DheerajJoshi: You need to read about the RecyclerView from https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Comment: thankyou @ישואוהבאותך